# C# .IndexOf Arraylist returns -1

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

So i have a listbox setup that has a couple library names inside in when you launch the program and when one is selected so i did this to get the contents of the selected item.

```
     string selectedItem = lstLibraries.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Then i wanted to find out where in the arraylist i have set up that this string appears so i used this.

```
    Libraries tempLibrary = (Libraries)LibrariesAndBooks[index];
```

As you can see in the screenshot below taken when the program had reached the error it is located at index[0] not -1 why is this happening?

[image: screenshot]

Also hardcoding it to be 0 is not an option for what i need to do and if i made a silly mistake or my code makes you want to throw up thats fine because I'm only in my first year of university and hadn't done any code in 6th form for whatever reason so it's to be expected.

Comment: `selectedItem` is a `string`, but your list seems to contain objects of a class. Using `IndexOf` is not going to work that way, as it doesn't know what it should compare the string to (it doesn't even know that it should compare the string to a member of an object), see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w3e62a8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to find a string in a collection of Libraries objects, which IndexOf cannot do.  You will have to iterate over the collection and test the name of each item against selectedItem, in order to find the index yourself.

You might even consider writing a reusable method to make tasks like this easier, going forward.  Something like:

```
    public static int FindIndex(IList collection, Func<object, bool> predicate)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
            if (predicate(collection[i]))
                return i;

        return -1;
    }
```

This way, you can solve this problem easily going forward as such:

```
int index = FindIndex(LibrariesAndBooks, (item) => ((Libraries)item).Name == selectedItem)
```

The easier, non-reusable method would look like this:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < LibrariesAndBooks.Count; i++)
{
    // Retrieve & soft cast - if it is a book, candidateLibrary will be null
    Libaries candidateLibrary = LibrariesAndBooks[i] as Libraries;
    if (candidateLibrary == null)
        continue;

    if (candidateLibrary.GetName() == selectedItem)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: You are assuming `lstLibrary.SelectedItem` is representing the actual object? According to OP it is a listbox that just contains copies of the `name`  members of the objects stored in `LibrariesAndBooks`

Comment: My mistake.  Will adjust.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what is happening in the code above as i need to be able to explain the code i have used so i can't just copy paste and adjust to get it to work.

Sorry if I'm being a pain, i know i could look up each bit to learn what it does but i probarly still wouldn't know what it does in this particular case :/

Comment: Sure.  The most difficult part of FindIndex to grasp is Func<object, bool> predicate, and it is also the most important.  This allows you to accept a function as a parameter, which FindIndex can then call.  In this case, it returns true (match) or false (no match), and we use it while iterating through the collection to determine if this is the item we are looking for.  If it is, we return the current index position.

When you call FindIndex, you can now pass in a function that simply determines whether or not some item is the one you are looking for.

Comment: In this case, that means determining if the object's name is equal to selectedItem, since selectedItem is really just an object name.

Comment: what is item in this case? because I'm only seeing it as a type and that doesn't seem right to me :/

Comment: This section here is a function:  (item) => ((Libraries)item).Name == selectedItem)

item is the variable/value that will be passed to it in FindIndex.  In this case, it is an object since ArrayList and IList are untyped, which is why we have to cast it before getting the name out of it (Assuming Libraries has a Name property).  It may look strange because no type is specified, but C# can usually infer the type in lambda functions.

It could be replaced with:  (object item) => ((Libraries)item).Name == selectedItem)

Comment: I updated my answer with a simpler solution in case you have too much trouble with the delegate/lambda.

Comment: yeah i think ill use the non-reusable one but when does index ever = i ?

And in my case we are using getters and setters so would i add .GetName where .name is in your examples?

Comment: => separates the parameter list from executable code in a lambda function.  If you write (parameterName) => 1 == 1, you have created a function that accepts a parameter and always returns true (because 1 always equals one).  In the case in my answer, we are checking item.Name (after some casting) to see if it is equal to selectedItem.

Comment: i updated my previous comment hoping you'd see it before you replied sorry but that helps with the lambda thank you :)

Ignore the first bit i realised you are setting index to i not testing if it is equal.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if you are only using the index to retrieve the item, you can remove the index from the equation altogether, and just set tempLibrary directly.  Instead of index = i, tempLibrary = (Libraries)LibrariesAndBooks[i].  If you change it from a for loop into a foreach loop, you could simplify it even further.  But I leave that to you.

Comment: in my case i wanted to use this index like so:

**Libraries tempLibrary = (Libraries)LibrariesAndBooks[index]; 


for (int i = 1; i < tempLibrary.GetNoOfBooks(); i++)
{
  Book tempBook = (Book)LibrariesAndBooks[index + i];
  lstLibraries.Items.Add(tempBook.Display()); 
 }**

how would i go about doing that because if i just do LibrariesAndBooks[index] ill be back at square one won't i?

Comment: It sounds like index was the right choice.  But in your search for a matching name, you are going to have to test the item's type before you try to cast it as Libraries.  Since it contains two types, you are going to run into an invalid cast exception with the code I provided.  I will update it.

Comment: Thank you for taking out so much time to work through this with me, i think i'll be okay with that code now, you've been a big help :)

Comment: We have all been new at some point.  Keep learning and good luck!